# use of of 'unlicensed' github code in research paper

Tags: publications

I have used github code for my research paper. But that code comes with no license. I have asked author to add license to code but he has not replied so far. Will this be a problem for me in future? I have not intentions for owning that code. I have just used that code without any changing and i would like to cite that repository link in my paper giving credit to original developer.
Please give your valuable suggestions

Comment: From an academic standpoint, I think citing the github repository and/or any related papers in your paper is actually quite sufficient. You’re not taking credit for the software - you’re acknowledging the creator, citing a link to the original source, and giving credit where credit is due.

Comment: @J.Tylka your comment is encouraging but all other links and answers have scary legal language. I have also contributed (a little) in the code to remove some bugs. But still the developer have successfully ignored my request to add license in the repo. Luckily, I have found another repo under MIT License by original creator of algorithm. Let's see what happens

Answer (score 35):

This topic is treated in [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5874/16807) on Open Source Stack Exchange. I reproduce it here because it might also be relevant for Academia. [The Open Source.SE answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5874/16807) points to [GitHub's "No License" page](https://choosealicense.com/no-permission/):

> If you find software that doesn’t have a license, that generally means you have no permission from the creators of the software to use, modify, or share the software. Although a code host such as GitHub may allow you to view and fork the code, this does not imply that you are permitted to use, modify, or share the software for any purpose.
>
> Your options:
>
> - **Ask the maintainers nicely to add a license.** Unless the software includes strong indications to the contrary, lack of a license is probably an oversight. If the software is hosted on a site like GitHub, open an issue requesting a license and include a link to this site. If you’re bold and it’s fairly obvious what license is most appropriate, open a pull request to add a license – see “suggest this license” in the sidebar of the page for each license on this site (e.g., MIT).
> - **Don’t use the software.** Find or create an alternative that is under an open source license.
> - **Negotiate a private license.** Bring your lawyer.

Note in the second line that you do not even have permission to **use** the software. Unfortunately, this means that, in order to be safe, you should either wait for the developers to reply to you and add the license, or write your own code.

Comment: Adding a license to an unlicensed repository may be a complex task. Only the copyright holder can license the code, which means that *every* contributor to the repository must individually agree to license the code under a new license. If there's only one contributor, then it's easy, as you only need that person. If there's more than one contributor it may be anywhere from easy to impossible to add a license to the repository. The maintainers can add a license that all *future* contributions are bound by, but they don't have the right to add-/re-license existing code which they didn't author.

Comment: For code deposit on StackExchange's sites like StackOverflow, see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315413/does-stackoverflows-code-licensing-override-my-previously-specified-license

Comment: Wondering - what is the legal reason for not being able to use (i.e. run) the code?

Comment: @usul this is probably a question for Open Source.SE or other more expert people. I do not think a claim against private use of GitHub code would hold up in court, but then again, using pirated commercial software from other sources is illegal (I think). This would mean that it is possible to legally disallow private use. IANAL, and software licensing is quite complicated...

Comment: @usul The legal reason is this: we have no idea why/how that code came to be in a public github repo. **It could be unpublished, private code, and the repository could have been created by its thief.**   Or various other situations in which evidently published code was not in fact intended to be published by its author.

Comment: @Kaz: I don't find that argument convincing, since essentially *nothing* in your comment changes if there *is* a license note.

Comment: @usul: What kind of answer are you looking for? The "technically correct" answer would be "because the law says so".

Comment: @usul AFAIK, that is the *default* - you cannot use copyrighted works in certain ways, unless the author says you can.

Comment: @Makyen Perhaps an ironic comment considering we are on SE, which has changed licenses without consent from copyright holders multiple times...

Comment: @usul: Good question, but too broad by far for a comment. Code is widely protected by copyright, but _running_ code is treated differently in different jurisdictions. In some, there's an implied license to use if legally obtained (e.g. from Github), which would be sufficient. Additionally, some jurisdictions have the notion of _fair use_, which then usually includes academic research, but again this is not universal.

Comment: @JörgWMittag We don't want to see just a license note, but a copyright and license header in every source file.  A bad agent (thief) could add those, sure; but a good agent (the author) adding all those headers by mistake is extremely unlikely. In any case, if we believe these copyright notices and licenses, we are acting in good faith, which should give us a measure of protection (should things come to that) if those notices turn out to be counterfeit.

Comment: @jgn Yeah, unfortunately, it is ironic. [I believe what SE has done with licensing is unlawful](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/333094/271271). The existence of prominent examples of organizations/people re-licensing unlawfully makes it important we inform people of the correct way of doing it. Adding/changing a license when more than one person/entity owns the copyright is usually a complex process. There are some large projects that have done so. If unable to get permission from the original contributors, it's necessary to rewrite the code, so those contributions are no longer in the repository.

Comment: @Kaz Different jurisdictions have different requirements with respect to inclusion of copyright notices and licenses. In many (most?) jurisdictions, a single copyright notice and license which covers all code in a repository is sufficient. The primary benefit of having such notices in each individual file is for situations where people separate individual files from the repository. Having those individual notices makes it easier for such users of the code to comply with the licensing terms, which usually require that the copyright notice and license be included with any copy.

Comment: @Makyen  Files get very easily separated from projects. Also, it's common for projects to include files from multiple authors (particularly in FOSS).  Files can also easily slip into projects, and thereby fall under the wrong license/copyright if they have none of their own. A single copyright file sitting in the root directory might be legal, but it's not sufficient. Every piece must be accounted for individually.

Comment: @Kaz It's the responsibility of the person that copied the file to make sure they are complying with the license requirements. It's not the responsibility of the authors/maintainers to make it easier for such people to do so, or to anticipate every possible way the code might be used. It is the responsibility of the people adding code to a project to make sure they are complying with the license for that code. Potentially, there *may* be some responsibility on the part of maintainers to at least have a statement putting responsibility on contributors.

Comment: We're rapidly getting into potentially complex legal issues, which are beyond the scope here. Ultimately, it's the responsibility of the person/entity using/copying the code to be sure it's licensed in a way that is compatible with their use. There are things authors/maintainers can do to make it easier for users to do so. Such things also make it more likely the license under which the code is released is complied with. However, authors/maintainers are *not required* to police other people's use of the code, unless the license under which they got the code requires them to do so.

Answer (score 11):

There's two different things to consider:

- Academic honesty - for this a citation will be fine. The emphasis here is on not claiming credit for the ideas of others, and by citing the repository appropriately you've done this. There's a slight concern here that if the code turns out not to be licensed in a way that's possible for people to use then it's harder for people to reproduce your results, but that's no different to making use of a proprietary tool (which is considered acceptable).
- Copyright/licencing/"are you legally allowed to use the code". I suspect the answer is "not really, but practically you will most likely get away with it". I also think this isn't really on-topic for this site. If it turns out you can't the consequences will likely be having to pay some compensation rather than an academic problem.

Probably the best solution would be to reimplement the algorithm in the repository yourself *and* cite the original source, thereby giving yourself the best chance of being legally fine while fulfilling your commitment to honestly acknowledging your sources. Note that this isn't the same as mechanically retyping their code - you should be aiming for a more high-level reimplementation.

---

**Small addendum:** it might be worth considering the source of the code. My experience is that a small-scale programs written for academic work (e.g. a data analysis algorithm from a mainly experimental group) are published without a license and without anyone ever really thinking about a license. The authors are generally very happy if the code is used because it shows someone's interested and gets a citation, but aren't hugely interested in formal licensing (which might involve painful interactions with university IP departments or similar). If the code comes from this kind of source then they'd probably be happy for you to use it (with a citation). This obviously doesn't provide legal clarity, but might give some re-assurance.

Comment: I disagree with respect to the academic honesty opinion.  If the user doesn't have license to the code, this could be viewed as piracy, and there are policies that define piracy as an academic ethics issue:  https://www.bvu.edu/policies/academic-honesty for example.

Comment: Granted, that is unlikely, but it is possible.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I don't completely disagree - more generally I many organisations probably view "obey local law" as a professional standard. However, my feeling is that most academic employers would be fairly non-judgemental given the circumstances described (assuming there isn't anything dodgy OP hasn't disclosed, of course). But I could see that if someone sued their institution over it then it could have consequences for them.